# Qual a diferença entre usar password_default e password_bcrypt?

Tags: php, criptografia, senhas

Pesquisando sobre hash, eu percebi que o segundo parâmetro da função `password_hash`, possui duas opções, `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` e `PASSWORD_BCRYPT`,

- Exatamente qual dos dois eu devo dar preferência para utilizar?

Provavelmente deve ser o `PASSWORD_DEFAULT`? Pois na documentação, é explicado ambos e dito que:

> **PASSWORD DEFAULT** - Use the bcrypt algorithm (default as of PHP 5.5.0). Note that this constant is designed to ***change over time as new and stronger algorithms are added to PHP***. For that reason, the length of the result from using this identifier can change over time. Therefore, it is recommended to store the result in a database column that can expand beyond 60 characters (255 characters would be a good choice).
>
> **PASSWORD_BCRYPT** - Use the CRYPT_BLOWFISH algorithm to create the hash. This will produce a standard crypt() compatible hash using the "$2y$" identifier. The result will always be a 60 character string, ou FALSE em caso de falha.

Então com essa citação pode-se supor que `Bcrypt` e `Crypt_Blowfish` são padrões diferentes, exatamente

- Qual seria a diferença entre eles?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Neste momento não há diferença.**

A diferença existente é que o `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` foi designado para mudar quando novos algoritmos forem adicionados, porém neste momento (*agora última versão é a PHP 7.1 para referencia*) o PHP apenas suporta o BCrypt.

No [PHP 7.2 está para vim o Argon2](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/argon2_password_hash), se isto realmente for feito poderá existir as opções, por exemplo:

```
PASSWORD_BCRYPT 
PASSWORD_ARGON2I
```

Dessa forma o `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` poderá mudar no PHP 7.3 de `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` para `PASSWORD_ARGON2I`, este é o proposito dele, por isto é avisado que ele pode mudar conforme o tempo.

*Porém neste momento não há diferença entre `PASSWORD DEFAULT` e o `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` .*

---

**Politicas de atualização do PASSWORD_DEFAULT**

- Qualquer novo algoritmo deve está disponível por pelo menos uam versão completa do PHP (full release) para se tornar `PASSWORD_DEFAULT`. Se o SCrypt for adicionado no PHP 5.5.5, ele não pode ser *DEFAULT* até que o PHP 5.7, porque o PHP 5.6 é o único "lançamento completo". Se o JCrypt for adicionado no PHP 5.6.0 ele pode se tornar padrão no PHP 5.7.
- O `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` apenas pode ser mudado num "versão completa" (full release, 5.5, 5.6, 7.0...) e não pode ser modificado nas versões de revisão (5.5.1, 5.6.1...) exceto se for uma emergência, como no caso de uma grave vulnerabilidade de segurança for encontrada no *DEFAULT* utilizado.

Answer (score 1):

Conforme descrito no manual, o recomendado é utilizar `PASSWORD_DEFAULT`.

A descrição informa que, atualmente, `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` utiliza `PASSWORD_BCRYPT`, o qual seria o algorítmo mais forte disponível, no PHP, para a criação de hash's de senha.

Por sua vez, o `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` utiliza `CRYPT_BLOWFISH`. Ou seja, conforme descrito:

> This will produce a standard crypt() compatible hash using the "$2y$" identifier.

É importante ressaltar que, `password_hash()` não é nada mais que um *wrapper* de `crypt()` com um gerador automático de *salt*, uma quantidade limitada e compatível de hash's para senha, ou conforme descrito em crypt():

> password_hash() is a simple crypt() wrapper and compatible with existing password hashes

A diferença entre utilizar `password_hash()` e apenas `crypt()` fica pelos *salt's* que são criados automaticamente pela função `password_hash()`. Conforme descrito nos seguintes trechos:

> password_hash() uses a strong hash, generates a strong salt, and applies proper rounds automatically.

E:

> salt - to manually provide a salt to use when hashing the password. Note that this will override and prevent a salt from being automatically generated.

No caso de `crypt()`, caso o *salt* não seja informado, ele não utilizará *salt* algum e criará um "hash fraco", que pode ser quebrado mais facilmente que um com um *salt*:

> The salt parameter is optional. However, crypt() creates a weak hash without the salt. PHP 5.6 or later raise an E_NOTICE error without it. Make sure to specify a strong enough salt for better security.

Já a descrição em `PASSWORD_DEFAULT`, é pelo fato de que, em algum futuro (próximo ou não) possa ser criado um algorítimo mais forte que `CRYPT_BLOWFISH` e ele se tornar o padrão para os novos *passwords*, tornando o `CRYPT_BLOWFISH` obsoleto. Por isso, é recomendado que os campos de senha tenham o tamanho de pelo menos 255. Pois, atualmente o `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` gerará um hash de 60 caracteres e, entretanto, um novo eventualmente poderá ser maior.