# Criptografia com bcrypt + salt aleatório

Tags: php, mysql, segurança, criptografia

Estou com uma dúvida simples quanto a criptografia usando o bcrypt com salt.

Quando em projetos antigos eu usava md5, para verificar em um form de login se o usuário digitou a senha correta e autenticar, era de costume pegar o valor que o usuário digitou e criptografar em md5 e procurar no bd.

Mas como no bcrypt usando salt aleatório não da para fazer isso, então eu fiz o seguinte:

Pego o email ou cpf que o usuário digitou no campo login, procuro no bd o registro correspondente e uso a senha armazenada no bd(hash) como salt e a senha digitada pelo usuário como a string na função crypt($string, $salt) e o retorno da função comparo com a senha armazenada no bd, e pela lógica a função deve gerar exatamente o próprio hash.

Segue um pedaço do meu código só para vocês entenderem melhor o que estou falando

```
 //Exemplo da busca com cpf
 $buscar = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE cpf =:cpf");
 $buscar->bindValue(":cpf", $login);
 $buscar->execute();
 $row = $buscar->fetch();

 //Armazena a senha que esta no bd
 $senha_armazenada = $row['senha'];

 //Comparação que estou fazendo
 if(crypt($senha_digitada, $senha_armazenada) === $senha_armazenada)
```

E isso está dando certo, mas quero saber se é a forma correta de se fazer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro, nunca faça isso:

```
if(crypt($senha_digitada, $senha_armazenada) === $senha_armazenada)
```

Qualquer string é um segredo nunca deve ser comparada usando `==` ou `===`, isso não é tempo constante e expõe a *timming-attack*. Isso não ocorre se usar `password_verify()` e nem `hash_equals`.

---

O `salt` é gerado dentro do da própria função, [inclusive eles já informam que definir um salt personalizado está "obsoleto"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/179749/por-que-a-op%C3%A7%C3%A3o-salt-do-password-hash-foi-descontinuado-no-php-7). Nem vou entrar no mérito da razão pelo qual eles fizeram isso.

Quando você faz:

```
password_hash('senha_legal', PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => 15])
```

A própria função obtêm um salt seguro (de um PRNG seguro) e faz a derivação da chave baseada na força definida. Não há necessidade de você gerar um salt, até porque a chance de você fazer isso errado (usando `rand()`, `mt_rand()` ou até `time()`) é muito maior.

---

No PHP 7.2 existe o `PASSWORD_ARGON2I`, que usa o Argon2i (vencedor do PHC) ao invés do BCrypt, neste caso use:

```
password_hash('senha_legal', PASSWORD_ARGON2I, ['memory_cost' => 1<<18, 'time_cost' => 4, 'threads' => 4])
```

*Também poderá usar o `sodium_crypto_pwhash_str()` que também usa Argon2i, ele já está disponível desde que instale o PECL.*

---

Sobre uso de *pepper* não existe muitas informações sobre isso, no caso do BCrypt isso pode piorar, porque irá reduzir o uso de até 72 bytes.

---

Além disso, assegure para que a senha inserida pelo usuário não possui `0x00` (bytes nulos), se não isso [`var_dump(password_verify('a', password_hash(pack('H*', '6100626364'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT)));`](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ca0466904dbb01475399a4bf2d0f77769fe71df8) retornará `true`, como já usei como exemplo em outras respostas.

Comment: Andei lendo a documentação do php sobre o password_hash e contém a seguinte informação a respeito do PASSWORD_DEFAULT "Observe que esta constante é projetada para mudar ao longo do tempo à medida que novos e mais fortes algoritmos são adicionados ao PHP". Tendo em vista a informação contida nesse trecho da documentação, não seria melhor sempre usar PASSWORD_DEFAULT ao invés de usar algum algoritmo em especifico? Já que o php vai se encarregar de sempre manter o algoritmo mais eficaz como padrão?

Comment: Eles vão demorar sempre uma versão inteira para mudar, *se* realmente mudarem. Eles só podem fazer isso na versão PHP 7.3 e não no PHP 7.2, que já vai ter esses  recursos. Acredito que é melhor que você escolha do que aguarde que outros tenham que escolher por você, [mas já tem uma pergunta sobre isso aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/194929/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-usar-password-default-e-password-bcrypt).

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que vi, está correto sim, mas da para melhorar. Recomendo você primeiro olhar o que você fez neste link:

http://blog.thiagobelem.net/criptografando-senhas-no-php-usando-bcrypt-blowfish

e uma solução mais atualizada está nesse link, usando uma api do `php`:

http://blog.thiagobelem.net/php-5-5-api-de-senhas

Desculpe eu não lhe explicar aqui já, mas encontrei esses artigos outro dia e ainda não implementei.

Comment: Pelo que entendi dessas funções então eu não preciso gerar um salt aleatório? a própria função password_hash() vai se encarregar disso? E se eu fizer algo como: password_hash("string", PASSWORD_DEFAULT) ele já iria gerar um hash com o bcrypt e salt?

Comment: Isso aí. Pelo que entendi a vantagem do `bcrypt` sobre o `md5` é que o primeiro funciona de uma forma mais lenta propositalmente para evitar ataques de força bruta e no caso do `hash_password` ele usa o `bcrypt` mas ele próprio cria o `salt` sem necessidade de sua intervenção como no `bcrypt`.

Comment: Ah e mesmo com essa segurança a mais, recomendo estudar a api do google `recaptcha` ou outra parecida. Aí sim você descarta ataque por força bruta no seu site. É bem fácil de implementar. https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/android.html