# o que eu devo fazer para autenticara usuario de maneira correta

Tags: php, sql, if, else

Estou precisando de ajuda para autenticar usuarios no meu site mas não sei o que a variavel sql que estanciei retorna quando acha o usuario certo o que eu coloco no if?

```
<?php 
include  'conexao.php';
$conexao = conexao::getInstance();

$login = $_POST['login']; 
$senha = $_POST['senha'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tabela  WHERE login = '$login' AND senha = '$senha'"; 

if ($sql== ? ) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['login']=$_POST['login'];
    $_SESSION['login']=$_POST['senha'];
    echo "login efetuado ";
    header("paineladm.php");
}else {
    echo "Login ou senha invalidos tente novamente...";

    header('login.php');
}
```

Comment: Primeiro, que API está utilizando para gerenciar o banco? `MySQLi` ou `PDO`? Segundo, leia sobre *SQL Injection*. Terceiro, se a última linha de código deveria redirecionar o usuário, faltou o nome do cabeçalho `Location`. Também não faz muito sentido você imprimir a mensagem no corpo da resposta se irá redirecionar.

Answer (score 0):

Validação de usuário e uma coisa delicada, você tem que pensar bastante na questão de segurança. Eu te indico usar PDO, da uma olhada no [manual](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.pdo.php).

> Vou deixar um exemplo simples pra você ter embasamento

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["login"])&& $_POST["login"]=="login"){
  $usuario = trim($_POST["usuario"]);
  $senha = trim($_POST["senha"]);

  if (empty($usuario)) {
    echo  "<script>alert('Informe o usuário!');</script>";
  }else if (empty($senha)) {
    echo  "<script>alert('Informe a senha!');</script>";
  }else{
    try {
      $stmt = $pdoMySql ->prepare("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt = $pdoMySql ->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE  usuario = ?, senha = ? LIMIT 1;");
      $stmt->bindParam(1, $usuario);
      $stmt->bindParam(2, $senha);
      $stmt->execute();

      //Se cair aqui e porque usuário exisste
      if ($linha = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        //Controle para sessão em outras páginas
        $_SESSION["loginok"] = true;
        //caso precisar esses dados em outras pagi8nas
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
        $_SESSION['senha'] = $senha;
        echo " <script language= \"JavaScript\"> location.href=\"index.php\"  </script>";
      } else {
        echo  "<script>alert('Usuário não existe!');</script>";
      }

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
      //erro
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: esse exemplo me ajudou bastante pude usa- lo no meu codigo sem problemas

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando o que o PHP fornece, você deve trabalhar com a funções [Password Hashing](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php) do PHP.

**password_hash**

Deve-se criar e armazenar o hash da senha em algum repositório (banco de dados, etc...). Para realizar o hash, você deve utilizar a função [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

```
$passwordHash = password_hash($_POST['password'] , PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

No primeiro parâmetro é a senha que você quer armazenar e o segundo é o algoritmo que será utilizado para a senha. Conforme o manual (que você também pode ler [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/194950/5007)), é recomendado utilizar `PASSWORD_DEFAULT`.

O hash que for gerado será sempre diferente, e, como exemplo, para a senha `teste123`, gerou o hash abaixo:

> $2y$10$kPsVvPp8Z1K73vEW/fHcHewbkkQNTN0JOdLPEwoydf8y4pO32Ixqu

Você pode verificar neste link a geração de hashs: https://3v4l.org/3eDee

**password_verify**

No momento de validar a senha, você deve utilizar a função [`password_verify`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). Conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```
password_verify ($_POST['senha'], $hash);
```

Sendo a variável `$hash`, o hash que foi retornado pela função `password_hash` e salvo no storage.

Exemplo:

```
$senha = "teste123";
$hash = '$2y$10$kPsVvPp8Z1K73vEW/fHcHewbkkQNTN0JOdLPEwoydf8y4pO32Ixqu';

echo password_verify ($senha , $hash) ? 'Senha válida' : "Senha inválida";
```

Saída:

> Senha válida

Código em funcionamento: https://3v4l.org/ksn1J

**Autenticação e Segurança**

Para melhorar ainda mais a segurança da autenticação, existem alguns passos a serem seguidos. O primeiro, é não diferenciar entre usuário ou senha inválidos. Pois, o atacando, saber que um usuário é válido, irá focar apenas nele para tentar localizar a senha.

Em segundo lugar, está algo chamado de Timming Attack. Que, resumidamente, consiste em verificar quanto tempo o algoritimo demora para responder que a senha é invalida e ir comparando estes tempos com senhas diferentes, para localizar caracteres corretos dentro de uma senha. Você pode ler sobre isso [neste link](https://blog.ircmaxell.com/2014/11/its-all-about-time.html)

A função `password_verify` já possui defesa contra Timming Attack, mas deve ser usada corretamente.

Com isso em mente, podemos chegar no seguinte script:

```
//criado utilizando o seguinte código: password_hash("dummy_password" , PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
define("DUMMY_PASSWORD" , '$2y$10$bev5nl962WWcwa1G2gyXyunkKY77Xf7OTr.1I3zcl7Qd4zFYCqXjC');

$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];

$pdo = new \PDO(/** dados de conexão**/);
$statement = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM user WHERE login = ?');
$statement->execute([$usuario]);
$row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(!$row)
{
    // Usuário não existe
    // A validação é feita em uma senha qualquer 
    //para que o tempo de resposta entre uma consulta que o usuário não exista
    //e uma consulta que o usuário exista e a senha esteja errada seja o mesmo.
    password_verify("" , DUMMY_PASSWORD);

    throw new \RuntimeException('Usuário/Senha não confere');//usuário não existe, mas a mensagem é genérica para evitar força bruta
}

if(!password_verify($_POST['senha'] , $row['password']))
{
    //usuário existe, mas a mensagem é genérica para evitar força bruta
    throw new \RuntimeException('Usuário/Senha não confere');
}

echo 'usuário logado';
```

Foi utilizada a biblioteca `PDO` para simplificar a conexão com o banco de dados e proteger contra *SQL Injection*.

Lembrando, este é apenas um algoritimo de exemplo, com uma forma segura e eficaz de login/autenticação. Os detalhes criação de sessão, redirecionamento, devem ser implementados conforme a necessidade.